# The type org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumOptions cannot be resolved. please find the attached screesh

Tags: java, selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver, cucumber

getting error here:

> The type org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumOptions cannot be resolved.

It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

```
private DriverDTO initializeTheChromeLocalDriver() {
    logger.info("launching the '{}' browser", browser);
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", SystemConstants.CHROME_DRIVER_PATH);
    Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  // prefs.put("download.default_directory", "C:\\Users\\pd\\Desktop\\AHNPTTest");
    prefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", true);
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs); // <-- this line throws exception
    if ("true".equalsIgnoreCase(SystemConstants.HEADLESS)) {
        options.setHeadless(true);
    }
    options.setUnhandledPromptBehaviour(UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.DISMISS);
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    options.addArguments(CapabilityType.SUPPORTS_JAVASCRIPT);
    WebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    return new DriverDTO(webDriver);
}
```

Comment: Please do not post images of code. Please [edit] your question to include the code, error message and stack trace as plain text. Use the `{ }` icon in the question editor to format the code.

Comment: here added the code

Comment: Which line of code is throwing the exception?

Comment: options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);  this line is throwing an exception

Comment: Can you add the 
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions; ?